# How to register and store user info in Firebase Real Time Database

Tags: angularjs, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I just want to know that how can i register user in Firebase and store user's additional details like First name, Last name etc i made a typical registration form in Angular I am successfully registering users with their user name and password but i want to store user's detail on success for future use. I've done this in angular 1 but could not find anyway to work with it Angular2

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to create a user object in your Firebase Realtime Database using the Firebase Authentication uid from the newly created user:

```
this.af.auth.createUser({
        // Create Firebase Auth user
        email: formData.value.email,
        password: formData.value.password
    }).then((user) => {
        // User created now create Firebase Database user
        return this.af.database.object(`/users/${user.uid}`).update({
            firstName: formData.value.firstName,
            lastName: formData.value.lastName
        });
    }).then(() => {
        // Success
    }).catch((error) => {
        // Error
        console.log(error);
    });
```

(Not had chance to test this)

Depending on how you've done registration you can obviously replace the `formData.value` with your model data if needed.

Also, this is done using the AngularFire2 library - https://github.com/angular/angularfire2